# Exclusive lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Is (or will be) there any sort of light linking in Cycles, or a method to get a light to affect only certain objects that doesn't involve compositing two or more different render layers? Sort of what 3Dstudio does with the Include/Exclude methods.

Comment: As of Blender 3.2 we now have [*Light Groups* in View Layer properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266833/how-to-properly-use-cycles-light-groups) for Cycles render engine

Answer (score 13):

In blender Internal you have 'light groups' specific for this purpose. Unfortunately, in Cycles this option is still on the [ToDo list](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/ToDo).
If you want to do this you'll need some compositing.

I made a small example:

[image: example]

- Be sure to set 'exclude' layers.
- For the ground plane i used a separate render layer with no exclude options so the drop shadow comes from both lamps.
- Check the 'transparent' option in the 'film' pane of the render setting. Otherwise the background is rendered as a solid color, defined in the world settings.

Answer (score 8):

If you are just trying to get rid of the reflection of the light source
[image]

You can turn off the visiblity for the camera and glossy on the emitting plane:

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would this be done for a Point Lamp in Cycles?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not yet possible in Cycles; It is, however, in the [To Do list](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.6/Source/Render/Cycles/ToDo).

It can be done rather easily in Blender Internal, though;

Comment: As of Blender 3.2 we now have [*Light Groups* in View Layer properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266833/how-to-properly-use-cycles-light-groups) for Cycles render engine