# How do I make objects ignore certain Light sources?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light

I have a scene which has a spot light as the main light source. To get the scene as bright as I want, I have to set the value for the strength to be quite high, something like 5000. The problem is, some textures get too bright and start losing details.

My question is, is there any way, maybe through nodes, to make an object not being influenced by a certain light source?

Thanks in advance
- Marten

Comment: You can use Ligth Linking http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Lighting/Lights/Lights_In_Other_Contexts

Comment: This answer of mine can be of a use for you - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/exclusive-lighting

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/164752/lighting-just-selected-objects

Comment: As of Blender 3.2 we now have [*Light Groups* in View Layer properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266833/how-to-properly-use-cycles-light-groups) for Cycles render engine

Answer (score 10):

This isn't possible in Cycles just yet; You will need to move those objects to a different Render Layer. However it is possible on Blender Internal, using one of these methods:

### Materials

By default, materials are lit by all lamps in all visible layers, but a material (and thus all objects using that material) can be limited to a single group of lamps. To enable this, navigate to the Material menu's Options panel and select a group of lamps in the Light Group field. Note that a light group must be created first.

If the Exclusive button is enabled, lights in the specified group will only affect objects with this material.

[image]

### Render Layers

You can also use *RenderLayers*. If a light group name is selected in this Light field, the scene will be lit exclusively by lamps in the specified group.

[image]

Check the relevant [wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Lighting/Lights/Lights_In_Other_Contexts).

Comment: Guessing by the tags, I think the OP wants to do this in cycles.

Comment: Not in cycles, not with light groups unfortunately.. It's on the todo list though.

Comment: Is this feature available yet in cycles?