# Can a material ignore a light?

Tags: rendering, materials, light, render-layers

I have several objects that need to be in the same scene layer and same render layers, but I want objects with a specific material to ignore a specific light. Is this possible?

Comment: Any solution I've found always seems to involve using separate scene layers and/or render layers.

Comment: Maybe with scripting? Or you could bake those objects without that light, and then make all lights have no influence.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15337/how-do-i-make-objects-ignore-certain-light-sources](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15337/how-do-i-make-objects-ignore-certain-light-sources) /  [http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/exclusive-lighting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/exclusive-lighting)?