# Lighting just selected objects

Tags: objects, light, lighting, scene

I have multiple objects in my scene and I have multiple light sources in it. How can I make that a certain light source affects just one selected object so it doesn't affect other objects in the scene? My render engine is Cycles.

Answer (score 2):

This feature is known as Light Linking, and it doesn't exist in Blender as of 2.81a

There is a todo item to include this in the future: https://developer.blender.org/T68915

What you can do is render in multiple view layers with only certain objects and lights together in a layer. Create multiple view layers, and enable/disable collections to include them in the view layer. The arrow icon sets a collection to 'indirect only', so the object itself is invisible, but it still contributes bounce lighting.

After rendering, the view layers need to be combined in the compositor.

[image: View layer demonstration]