# How to properly use Cycles Light Groups?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, light-groups

Recently in Blender's new 3.2 updates, we got *Light Groups*, however, they are rather hard to use them without knowing what to do.

How do the new Cycles *Light Groups* work, and how to use them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that *Light Groups* are only available for Cycles at the moment.

The [3.2 Cycles Release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/3.2/Cycles) describe Light Groups thusly:

> a type of pass that only contains lighting from a subset of light sources.
> This can be used in order to e.g. modify the color and/or intensity of light sources in the compositor without re-rendering.

[Here is one of many video tutorials](https://youtu.be/3O_QPW2V2hY), currently all about 3.2 alpha, but the release version isn't very different.

In summary:

- There is a new property in the *View Layer* tab called *Light Groups*. Create new light groups there.
  [image: View Layer Properties showing Light Groups]
- Lights have a new *Object Property* under *Shading* called *Light Group*.  You assign each light that you want in a light group to the new light group here.  You can bypass the first step by clicking the '+' button to create a new lightgroup, but there's a bug and the light isn't automatically assigned, so you have to assign it anyway.
  [image: Light object properties showing Light Group under shading]
- Effectively, each light group is a Render Layer pass, that contains the lighting from the specified group. You use it in the compositor to modify the lighting. The easy example is changing color.

Here's a contrived example.  Suzanne is lit from

- front with a blue area light, the sole light in the front group
- back with a red area light, the sole light in the back group
- sides two green area lights, both in the side group:

[image: A badly lit Suzanne]

Here's a render:

[image: Render with all lighting]

Here's the compositor, showing only the side lighting:

[image: Compositor showing only green lighting]

One could mix the three lighting groups in the compositor, adjusting the color balance of each separately, for instance:

[image: mixing all 3 light groups]

That is, the color group passes can be used in the compositor the same way any other pass could be.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: @YousufChaudhry you're very welcome.  I suspect light groups are going to become very popular.