# how to keep specific light sources from effecting an object

Tags: lighting, glass, render-layers

I'm having a problem where I need to have light sources illuminate an object with a glass material to get it to look brighter. My issue is that the lights shine through the material and glow on to the surface outside

[image: Glow I need removed]

I would use view layers but that got me a result that made the surface look transparent

[image: Transparent Hair]

I need to know if there is a way to get the light to still illuminate the gemstones on the crown but also not spill through to illuminate anything else.

These are the settings I use on each light with their respected colors

[image: Light Settings]

My blend file is a bit too large to send over the internet so let me know if I should recreate the issue in a new file

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/exclusive-lighting/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266833/how-to-properly-use-cycles-light-groups