# Is there a way to have my emission shader only affect the particle system?

Tags: particles, shaders, render-layers

I have a scene that has a particle system and other objects. The particles are an object with a pure glossy shader. I have a plane that I have setup as an emission shader to reflect off the particles. However it is washing the other object in the scene. Is there a way to have my emission shader only affect the particle system?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [light groups](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Lighting/Lights/Lights_In_Other_Contexts). Well, the light groups feature hasn't been implemented in Cycles yet. If you wanna separate lighting on different objects, including particles, using Cycles, you might use render layers. [Here's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/exclusive-lighting) a solution for a practically the same question as yours.