# Light Groups in v2.73

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I want to make an object be affected by specific light sources. How can I make that happen? From what I've read, older Blender versions have it laid out in the Materials and Render Layers tabs.

Comment: I don't think this has changed - just double check that you are using Blender Render and not Cycles (since Cycles doesn't have light groups at all)

Comment: @GregZaal is correct. there is *no possible* way to do this in cycles. just like for a while you could not make smoke or fire in cycles, it is the same here. (It is possible they will be re-creating light groups for cycles in the future though)

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/983/599