# Change the effect of a light on a certain object?

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, light

I need a *Rim / Backlight* for my object, but the mesh is standing on a Glossy floor and when I put a spot lamp even which is pointing upward, it is still casting light on the floor, which is something I do not want.

**Is there a way to make the Lamp not to be able to affect the Floor or make the floor to ignore the Lamp ?**

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/983/599

Answer (score 3):

Here's a screen shot showing the sort of compositing setup you'll want to make.

There is an orange lamp shining from the top left of the shot, and a blue lamp shining from the top right. The floor plane is ignoring the blue light while the cube and cylinder objects are receiving light from it.

[image: Separating objects and lighting by compositing render layers]

First, for this to make sense you need to know the difference between ***layers*** and ***render layers***. A ***layer*** is a slot where objects can reside. A ***render layer*** specifies for a type of render to be made by arranging ***layers*** in a special way.

So that you can see which objects are on which ***layers***:

[image: Layer labels]

(I can label the layers because I'm using the Layer Management add-on)

Here are the Mask and Exclude settings for the ***render layers***:

[image: Mask and Exclude settings for render layers]

### Explanation of render layer settings

**Main Render Layer:** *Layer 2* which contains the floor plane is masked out.

**Floor Plane:** Excludes *Layer 3* which contains the blue lamp. Masks out *Layer 1* which contains the cube and cylinder.

Note that it's not even necessary to enable the "Blue Spot Lamp" ***render layer*** for the blue lamp to have an effect as long as the ***layer*** it resides on is enabled. Disabling that render layer speeds up render time.

[image]

More info: [Understanding Render Layers](https://cgcookie.com/archive/tip-understanding-render-layers/)