# How to make a material not reflect light?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light, lighting

I have 2 Finishes in cycles,

1) with a glossy >> roughness is 0.5 (Lets call this as
**Roughness0.5**)

2) with a glossy >> roughness is 0.05 (**Roughness0.05**)

I want roughness0.5 to reflect light.,
but
I dont want Roughness0.05 to reflect light because the light reflection looks weird here.
[image]

At the same time, I can't turn of the glossy in the cycles settings for an object for any chance.

Is there any way to do this?
Do I have to play with the light path nodes?

Comment: I believe that the whole nature of shaders is to reflect light back at the camera (just as real life). If you want a material to just absorb light, you could make it a #000000 colored emissive shader.

Comment: Please find what exactly i need here..

https://scontent-sin6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15590505_1222508567845994_4984324993204822974_n.jpg?oh=e37449f09c742d12f7198ad8be47b7cf&oe=58EA1871

i need the specularity on the object (as marked in blue)
But i dont need miror to reflect light (as marked in red)

So, there is anything to do with material?

basically, the left sphere will be a half glossy wood.

Comment: Cycles doesn't work that way. To make it not look weird, use real lights (like an hdri, not a simple point or plane).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclusive lighting](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/exclusive-lighting)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a ***Toon Shader*** instead of *Glossy* one. It's not the proper, accurate way of doing this IMO, but the final result is close to what you're looking for I guess.
[image]

Use a *Lamp* instead of *emission plane*.
[image]

Set the ***Toon Shader*** to *Glossy* and decrease the *Size* to *0.001* and *Smooth* to *0.000*.
[image]