# How do I link a light only with some specific objects in a scene?

Tags: rendering, light, lighting

I am a MAYA user for last 12 years and I am making my transition to Blender these days and I found Blender is far more superior than MAYA only with some exceptions. 
Light linking is an one thing I find it easily done in MAYA (I still don't know if there is any easy way Blender does it better)

So what I want to do is, as an example, I have this room in Blender and I want a light illuminate only the walls in the room not any other objects in the scene???

Here is my scene.
[image]

Here is a WIP render of it.
[image]

As you can see walls are not lighten. I want walls to be seen slightly without adding any more light spill on other objects in the center.

Thanks...

Comment: Please immediately tag your question with either Cycles Render or Blender Render.

Comment: I think it will be a feature only in the next Blender (2.8) as explained by the Blender team

Comment: I remember I saw it somewhere in a tutorial video, that we can make light groups or object groups to do something closer to assigning lights separately but I cannot remember exactly what was the tutorial.

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/983/29586